# C11/C17: Explicit casting char* to uint8_t* leads to a -Wpointer-sign warning

Tags: c, llvm

So I get this warning

> warning: passing 'char[6]' to parameter of type 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') converts between pointers to integer types where one is of
> the unique plain 'char' type and the other is not [-Wpointer-sign]

from compiling the following code which calls a `void my_func(uint8_t *)` function:

```c
my_func(UINT8_C("world"));
```

`UINT8_C` is from `stdlib.h`

IIRC the same thing happened when using

```c
my_func((uint8_t)("world"));
```

I would have expected that the explicit cast does away with the warning, why not?

Comment: You're casting a char[] constant to a `uint8_t` which doesn't make a lot of sense -- a pointer will not fit in 8 bits.  You're then implicitly converting that single byte into a pointer (`uint8_t` to `uint8_t *`) which is pretty much guarenteed to give you a garbage pointer.   I would expect multiple warnings from this.  What are you trying to do?  Perhaps you actually want `my_func((uint8_t *)"world");`?  Casting a char pointer to a uint8 pointer.

Comment: @wirrbel, for a _good_ answer, consider posting the calling code, its surrounding code and at least some of `my_func()`, to provide context on the best way to handle this.

Comment: You'll need to use `my_func((uint8_t *)"world")` to convert the `char *` derived from `"world"` into a `uint8_t *` — even though it is a no-op (it doesn't change the number passed to the function as the address).  Using the `u8` prefix (`u8"world"`) doesn't help: [§6.4.5 String literals ¶6](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6) says: _For UTF-8 string literals, the array elements have type `char`, and are initialized with the characters of the multibyte character sequence, as encoded in UTF-8._ So the cast would be necessary even with the UTF-8 prefix.

Comment: Actually, the `u8` prefix would be OK (but superfluous) if the plain `char` type is equivalent to `unsigned char`.  By default, on many machines, the plain `char` type is a signed type (equivalent to `signed char`).  Th `u8` prefix would unambiguously indicated that the string is intended to be UTF-8, though, and that specificity could be helpful.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler And _"on many machines"_ means nearly 100% of them nowadays if I'm not mistaken. I've only come in contact with mainstream machines so perhaps there's still somewhere where `char` is unsigned.

Comment: If you manage to come across a machine that uses EBCDIC, @TedLyngmo, then the plain `char` type will be unsigned so that the digits and letters are positive values.  But I could probably have written 'most' instead of just 'many' and still have been accurate.  It's odd to me — an unsigned `char` would be simpler and useful in all sorts ways. I assume that there is a good reason for it, such as the sign extension of the lower 8-bits of a register to full 32-bit or 64-bit is presumably more efficient than unsigned extension, but I've not studied the instruction sets of machines to know for sure.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler :-) You are careful and I find that lovely!

Comment: OpenWatcom C compiler targeting i386 has char unsigned by default.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on the compiler and the settings, char may be signed or unsigned. You may want to use `clang -funsigned-char`.

Comment: If the problem was simply the pointer type, this might be OK, but there is a more significant problem — the `UINT8_C()` macro chops 7 of the 8 bytes (or perhaps 3 of the 4 bytes) of the address of the value being passed to the function, and creates an integer type (which is then converted to a pointer by the prototype), whereas the function expects a pointer type.  So the use of `UINT8_C()` is wholly inappropriate and any answer must stipulate this.  It can then offer remedies for the problem, and one possibility might be to choose `-funsigned-char` (which works with both GCC and Clang).

Comment: In addition to neglecting the other issues in the code, this answer does not even solve the problem it purports to solve. As the warning message in the question states, the warning is because the source type is the “plain 'char' type” and the destination not. Adding `-funsigned-char` does not change that fact. It may cause `char` to have the same behavior within the program as `unsigned char`, but it does not change it to be `unsigned char`. `char` remains a distinct type from both `signed char` and `unsigned char`. Testing with Clang shows the switch does not eliminate the warning.